# HTAccess HTTPS redirect along with multiple other redirects

Tags: .htaccess

My current HTAccess file looks like this and it works

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^ /public/index.php [L]
```

I want to redirect all HTTP traffic to HTTPS all the while redirecting .com traffic to .co.uk, so I tried the below but none of them worked.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.domain.co.uk/public%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

I also tried the various answers from other Stackoverflow questions but none of them worked for me. Currently my website is set to read the index.php (Laravel) file to load when my domain name is called. I'm not sure how to incorporate that (or even use it adjointly with HTTPS redirection.

Comment: The redirection rule looks fine. Keep in mind that you need to take care of the order of redirections if you use distributed configuration files (".htaccess"). That redirection must come _before_  the internal rewrite, so further up in the file. But after enabling the rewriting engine.

Comment: "redirecting `.com` traffic to `.co.uk`" - Your current directive does not reference `.com` at all? Only if it does not start with `www.`.